Opening notification tab with removed notification doesn't clear them
I recently got notification while I was on SO. I clicked on the "Inbox" button, but there is no new notification even if the "1" is already displayed and keep to be showed.
Here I check notification because of the "1" :

After closing the tab, it's already there :

Step to reproduce :

Open a page on Stack Overflow
Receive a notification (but do NOT open inbox tab)
Make the notification disappear (delete things that created the notification, I think)
See notification -> you will keep the "1"

(Note: Actually, I don't really know what created this "ghost" notification. I think it should be a comment or something related)

Pressing "Mark all as read" normally helps. At worst, you could refresh the whole page.

@Tsyvarev right, that's just more a description of the bug than a fix.
